# pdb-mmem flag of memory_profiler not working

Tags: python, memory, profiler

I would like to hunt for a memory leak. For that --pdb-mmem flag from memory_profiler would be really helpful.

profiling this script test.py:

```
import time
from memory_profiler import profile

@profile
def my_func():
    a = [1] * (10 ** 6)
    b = [2] * (2 * 10 ** 7)
    del b
    return a

if __name__ == '__main__':
    my_func()
```

with: `python -m memory_profiler --pdb-mmem=10 test.py`

results in:

```
Line #    Mem usage    Increment  Occurences   Line Contents
============================================================
     4     33.6 MiB     33.6 MiB           1   @profile
     5                                         def my_func():
     6     41.2 MiB      7.6 MiB           1       a = [1] * (10 ** 6)
     7    193.9 MiB    152.7 MiB           1       b = [2] * (2 * 10 ** 7)
     8     41.4 MiB   -152.6 MiB           1       del b
     9     41.4 MiB      0.0 MiB           1       return a
```

but does not stop in line 7 as stated in:

```
--pdb-mmem MAXMEM     step into the debugger when memory exceeds MAXMEM
```

what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

As an alternative, consider using https://pythonspeed.com/fil. Specifically, it reports source of allocations at *peak* memory, so if you leak enough memory the result will be dominated by the leaked data and you can figure out which lines of code were responsible for allocating that.

(If source of leak is not obvious you will still need to use other tools to figure out why that memory isn't being freed, e.g. Pymplyer's muppy. That's true of memory-profiler too.)

Comment: This isn't really an answer. Besides, it's a good gesture to mention it explicitly that you are  (one of) the authors of something you are suggesting :).